# ExactTarget API - get report of all emails sent SOAP::Lite example

Tags: marketing-cloud

Trying to use PERL SOAP::Lite module to get email sent report from the ET API. Anyone have success using the examples here in PERL:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/

Comment: Are you not having success?  Do you have a print out of the SOAP envelope being created by your code? Any error responses?

Comment: Thanks. I have this working now. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to get the filter working. Anytime I tried to add filter tags, I get a "Bad Request" error.

Comment: Glad you are able to get it working. Post some of your working code below. In a couple days you will be able to check it as answered.  Then create a new question with the non working filters, and we can have a look. Try to be detailed in your questions so we can help out. Thanks!